# How to make two different appendice chapters with two different names

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I am trying to produce 2 different `\begin{appendices}` with two different  names, where one uses numbers, and the other uses letters.

I have experimented with it, myself, but to no avail.

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{appendix}

\begin{appendices}

    \chapter{this needs to be called "Appendix A"}
        \label{appA}

    [content of appendix A]

    \chapter{this needs to be called "Appendix B"}
        \label{appB}

    [content of appendix B]

\end{appendices}

\begin{appendices}

    \chapter{this needs to be called "Bilag 1"}
        \label{bil1}

    [content of bilag 1]

    \chapter{this needs to be called "Bilag 2"}
        \label{bil2}

    [content of bilag 2]

\end{appendices}
```

This only yields resetting the numbering, so it's now Ap A, Ap B, Ap A, Ap B

Is it possible to rename and renumber two different appendice, so it's Ap A, Ap B, Bi 1, Bi 2 ?

Comment: If i change `appendices` to be `appendix` to make the example a little more compilable and add a proper `document` environment ... I get Bilag A to Bilag D. Please edit your question so we see what you are describing.

Comment: @Johannes_B , Thank you, it's fixed now. Also, see Bernards answer, for the solution to my problem.
What do you mean by "Proper document environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `appendices` packagedoes not exist, as far as I know, but the `appendices` environment is defined by the `appendix` package.. Here is a simple solution:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, fleqn, twoside, openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{appendices}

    \chapter{this needs to be called "Appendix A"}
        \label{appA}

    [content of appendix A]

    \chapter{this needs to be called "Appendix B"}
        \label{appB}

    [content of appendix B]

\end{appendices}

\begin{appendices}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}

    \chapter{this needs to be called "Bilag 1"}
        \label{bil1}

    [content of bilag 1]

    \chapter{this needs to be called "Bilag 2"}
        \label{bil2}

    [content of bilag 2]

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Bernard, works like a charm. Now i only have one issue left, born from this solution. 
All the appendices are now called "Bilag X" in my ToC, where those named Appendix, obviously should be named that in the ToC as well. Do you know any fix to this also?

Answer (score 2):

I do not have package `appendices`. But with `memoir` there is no additional package needed:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,twoside
  %,openright
  ,openany% <- only for the example
  ]{memoir}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\renewcommand{\restoreapp}{}% <- added

\begin{document}

\begin{appendices}
    \renewcommand\appendixname{Appendix}% <- added

    \chapter{this needs to be called Appendix A}
        \label{appA}

    [content of appendix A]

    \chapter{this needs to be called Appendix B}
        \label{appB}

    [content of appendix B]

\end{appendices}

\begin{appendices}

    \chapter{this needs to be called Bilag 1}
        \label{bil1}

    [content of bilag 1]

    \chapter{this needs to be called Bilag 2}
        \label{bil2}

    [content of bilag 2]

\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

[image]